# How to convert AnyPublisher<DataResponse<T, Error>, Never> to AnyPublisher<T, Error>

Tags: swift, combine

`DataResponse` is the object of Alamofire. It returns `Decodable` object and `Error` in success itself in .

Requirement is to pass on received `Decodable` object and `Error` separately. Is it feasible to transform `AnyPublisher<DataResponse<T, Error>, Never>` to `AnyPublisher<T, Error>`.

Consider `T` as any data type object.

```
func fetchDataViaAlamofire(usingURl url: String) -> AnyPublisher<T, Error> {
        return AF.request(url,
                          method: .get)
        .validate()
        .publishDecodable(type: T.self)
        .map { response in
            
            // ?
            // Cannot convert value of type 'DataResponse<T?, AFError>' to closure result type 'T'
            response.map { value in
                return response.value
            }
            
            // ?
            // Any way to convert AFError to Error in AnyPublisher<T, Error>
        }
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have to add the generic parameter `T` in the signature of the method.

AF provides the operator `.value()` to convert the types. Additionally you have to map/cast `AFError` to `Error`

```
func fetchDataViaAlamofire<T: Decodable>(usingURL url: String) -> AnyPublisher<T, Error> {
    return AF.request(url, method: .get)
        .validate()
        .publishDecodable(type: T.self)
        .value()
        .mapError{$0 as Error}
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Comment: thanks for this answer. saved my time. Regarding T, I do agree with you that T should have been mentioned in function declaration. In my code T belongs to my generic class, and forgot to mention this while asking this question.